# How to show the elements of a UITableViewCell (eg labels, buttons) only after data from an asynchronous call is returned?

Tags: swift

I have a tableView in a UIViewController.
There is also a class called CustomCell which represents the tableView cell. In the CustomCell class I have a label and a button. Whether the button is shown (ie button.isHidden) depends on whether a field in firestore is true or false.

The issue i have is that because I have placed the button in the cell on the storyboard it is shown for about a second until firestore returns with true/false and if its false then button.isHidden = true and the button disappears.

I know one option is to just set the button to hidden initially and if the firestore query returns true then I can show the button.

But I have been trying to use completion handlers/closures where possible but I couldn't figure out how I might do that in this situation.

Essentially i'd want the firebase query in func like:

```
func buttonShow(completion: ()->()){          
     //the firebase query here
     query?.getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in

     if let err = err
     {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        return
     }
     else
     {
        //get the value ie either true or false
        completion()
     } 
}
```

But I wasn't sure from where I would call this function. I think I would need to call it in cellForRowAt.

Parts of these classes are below:

// UIViewController and the cellForRowAt function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else
    {
       fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of ProjectProtoCell.")
    }

    let user : User = changeDataSource(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath) 
       cell.nameCell.text = user.firstname
       // do I call the button show function here?
    }
}
```

// CustomCell.swift

```
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code   
    }

    func buttonShow(completion: ()->(){
            see code above
    }
}
```

Thx.

Comment: I don't see any significant drawbacks with setting all buttons hidden at first.

Comment: I think hiding initially and showing later is fine. But...

Is it for one single cell? Or are you going to have hundreds of cells? What happens if the user starts scrolling the tableview real quick? Will it make hundreds of calls? Do you want to make network calls for only the visible cells and cancel the network calls for other non visible cells? Maybe you want to use an operationqueue? Maybe something like this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift